# Codemirror - how to write own code editor in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo

I need to write my own [code editor](http://codemirror.net/) in browser. I found `CodeMirror` but I don't understand how to do this. I need simple code.

Can I use `textarea` or something else? (for example content editable). How to underline, colorize, auto complete the code?

Please, give me some advice. I will be very grateful.

I've read a book from O'Reilly, Douglas Crockford, about JS so I've some basics.

Comment: "I know basic JS, show me how to write an IDE" .. is not what stackoverflow is about. Each item you mention, "underline, colorize" etc is a question on its own provided you already had some grounding.

Comment: I don't want to be harsh, but if you're asking this question then you're not going to be able to write a decent in-browser code editor any time soon. CodeMirror is an excellent piece of software; why not use it?

Comment: Also, CodeMirror's author has written several articles about the innards and devlopment process of CodeMirror 1 and 2 which are prominently linked from the home page of the site. Reading those would give you an excellent background to challenges involved.

Comment: @TimDown I want to learn - so I want to (try) write syntax editor. I will be use Code Mirror source code of course - but I need more experience to understand every line of code. That is the reason why I write this post, at first I need to know how to write - how is build - how is working.

I saw it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @JoshSmeaton As I write in my last post - "but I need more experience to understand every line of code. That is the reason why I write this post, at first I need to know how to write - how is build - how is working." 

Yep, but I have a difficult to try understand how it works - buddhabrot very good explain it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the html behind a code editor example page. Use WebKit's (Safari/Chrome) "Inspect Element".

As you can see there is a large div over a textarea that holds individual strings, so the user just gets the "illusion" he is typing in a textarea. The textarea is still there but it is not what you really are seeing.

If you want syntactical coloring you will need lexicographic analysis of the string, which is usually done by a lexer that outputs tokens. These tokens are caught by a process that collects them in individual div's that have f.i. the same text color. Then that div overlays the textarea.

If you want to go deeper in the code you will also need semantic parsing and a lot of coffee to program all of that.

Good luck, do you know you're taking on something big? And why would you reinvent this, it's already been done superbly by others.

Comment: Heh. I know that is very big but... I've to do my own version, because is a project for innovation competition, and I've to put in a lots of modifiaction :)  it wil be more and more bigger :) (PHP, maybe cloud) 

Also I will be follow existing projects. :)


Do you know, is it possible to auto-complete or auto-advice syntax?

And what technology/framework is the best to challenge this?(AJAX, Jquery, Dojo or clean JS or sth else) :)

Thanks a lot for a very important advice! :) Every clue is for me very important :)

Comment: The best way is to reuse the parsing technology from something else, I can't see why using the "cloud" would make any difference with the client behaviour: it's just parsing text. Honestly, I don't mean this bad but I think you don't really know what you're doing. Just chill out and try to reuse what's there.

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski being innovative means coming up with an idea of your own. Not tacking on keywords to existing technology. You're in way over your head. What is your previous background?

Comment: @buddhabrot Of course - it's just parsing, but it will be more than only parsing code. I write that it is beggining.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton What you mean about background? About my idea?


Guys xd I've head in "cloud" because I'm 18 years old and my abitions grow up :)

Comment: @Gabriel Żukowski -- every programmer except you has, from the beginning of time, learned how something works by *reading the code!* Why do you find this so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [**tinyMCE**](http://www.tinymce.com/) if uou haven't already.

Comment: I mean syntax editor :) what i know tinyMCE is WYSIWYG content editor and is implemented in some CMS.